# Overriding/customizing Drupal modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

I would like to override custom user template in my Drupal 7 installation. The question is - should I edit the template file in the main module or copy the module to my theme's folder and edit it there? In case of the second option, how can I do it?

Comment: Which template are you editing specifically? You should almost definitely not edit the template file in the module itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely create a subtheme to customize the look and feel. Otherwise, every time you upgrade core you will have to reapply your changes. You can subtheme the default Drupal 7 theme (Bartik) by following [these steps](http://drupal.org/node/800510#comment-3277090).

Once you have done that, copy the user-profile.tpl.php file into your subtheme directory (/sites/all/themes/mytheme).

Finally, make the changes you want to make to user-profile.tpl.php